# library dll (nuget) replace with source code(git hub) and vice versa when needed

Tags: github, nuget

I use a library from nuget (eg: IdentityServer 3) , in my solution.

Once in a while when I want to debug I want to attach the source code(eg: IdentityServer 3) from github instead of the dll.

One way is remove the dll and add the project to the solution and run. And vice versa.

Is there any other quick way. i.e less changes in solution. all I need to debug the source code better but do not want to keep the whole source code in solution.

Comment: Why do you want to debug an external package? I you think there's a defect, just report the issue with reproduction path to the author.

Comment: The defect could be in my code. May be I am not filling the parameters properly in settings/config.  I found I was able to fix the problem easily by having the source code in it. Anyways this is a question about the possibility to swap